# Automatic ways to identify variables of importance in the presence of multicollinearity (prior to PCA)

Tags: pca, feature-selection, multicollinearity

From an ecological experiment, I have time series data with 10 time points where I measured around 100 variables (shape and texture traits of algae cells) across 4 treatments (A-D). Now I would like to do a PCA (or some other form of ordination) to visualize treatment specific change in traits over time. As shown in the cartoon below, in timepoint 1 all treatments would be similar in traits (hence proximity in PC space), whereas over the course of the experiment they would diverge (to different places in PC space at timepoint 10):

[image]

Many of those 100 traits are correlated, and not just pairwise, but many among many (multicollinearity). I would like to boil the dataset down to the minimal amount of variables with which I can represent the PC space of all 100 variables - i.e., plotting PCs of those traits vs. all 100 variables would look similar.

My problem is that I don't think the typical methods for variable selection prior to PCA work: because there are so trait variables and so many correlations among them, most explain only around 2% of the variance. I have done correlograms and manually removed some variables, but this seems arbitrary and unsystematic.

**My question is whether there is some sort of automatic solution for variable selection to identify variables of importance that account for most of the variation in the data structure?**

---

EDIT: Based on the comments I am providing some more information: a PCA on the entire dataset (all timepoints and treatments) indicates that 50% of variation are explained by PC1. My goal would be to have the selected variables explain 90% of the variation and that this would require 11 PCs (90% is arbitrary, but I don't know where do make a cutoff given that there is no clear break):

[image]

**Instead of dropping variables, another, potentially more sensible approach could be to construct new hyper-variables based how clustered the original ones are in the data space (irrespective of treatments and timepoints).** This would eliminate multicollinearity, and make the proposed ordination/visualization via PCA more meaningful, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: It's difficult to determine what you're describing, because it *seems* you are referring to the dependent variables as "features" and are somehow using them to "explain variance," but this language is reserved for *independent variables* (and makes little or no sense for dependent ones).  Moreover, it's not part of the concept of dependent variables to be able to "remove" them: the whole point is to fit or predict *all* of them. Could you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: you could try a quotient space with the relation ```column1 ~ column 2 ``` iff ```corr(column1,column2) > THRESHOLD_VALUE```. then select only one feature per classs

Comment: @whuber I modified the question: while these are technically features, and I use them to explain variance in overall feature/trait space, this probably led to false associations.

Comment: @LuisFelipe this won't work because there are so many traits correlated with many other traits, i.e., column1 could be correlated with column2, but also with column 12 and column77. I am afraid to lose higher level interactions among my variables like that

Comment: have you checked the meaning of “quotient class”?

Comment: @LuisFelipe is it the same as "quotent set" https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594458/definition-of-quotient-set? Would you care to elaborate by writing an answer?

Comment: Okay, just give a few hours because in my timezone is 3:57 am :)

Comment: The quotient space approach is *ad hoc* and unlikely to succeed generally.  Instead, have you considered applying PCA to the entire dataset?  That would help establish an upper bound on the number of variables (= number of PCs) you need.  If that bound is large, next try generalized nonlinear methods: these approximate your data with low-dimensional curvilinear manifolds.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction) for an overview. [Philip Waggoner's new book](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.06885) looks like a good, accessible introduction.

Comment: I used quotient space to select only 1 representant per class. My equivalence relation means that it groups the correlated columns (2, 3, 5, n columns on the same quotient element), then you select (in base one criteria) only 1 element per representant class. I haven't see any documentation of this, as mathematician this was the logic way to attack the redundant information of correlated features. This approach improved the accuracy of my logistic regression model from 75% to 92% on transactional data from customs, and also neural network models that I've used.

Comment: For dimension reduction, instead of PCA, I have seen better results to divide classes on t-SNE method, but this is a more complex method very explosive respect its parameters. You can check this site https://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/ in order to get a better comprension of the parameters

Comment: @Luis I am glad that method seems to work for you.  However, it has no statistical justification, is arbitrary (which of each pair of variables do you retain?), and is inferior to most methods developed in the last 40 years that capitalize on the full information in the variance-covariance matrix instead of just the pairwise correlations.

Comment: @whuber you can try and see if it helps, and it has an mathematical justification: every clustering technique is equivalent to a quotient space :)

Comment: @Luis Only in a statistically trivial way.

Comment: No my friend, every hard relation that describes a clustering process is an equivalent relation. Every partition of a set describes an equivalent relation  and every equivalent relation describes a partition of a set.

Comment: @Luis I don't disagree.  But your statements are (elementary) conclusions from the definitions of equivalence relation and partitions.  They have no statistical content or useful implications for statistical procedures.